# How to make sub-domain points to an route in my app?

Tags: apache

If I have a subdomain `x.example.com` and want this subdomain pointing to `example.com/path` without any redirect and URL changing in the browser?

Notes:

- `example.com/path` not points to a new app but a route in `example.com` app
- I am using `apache` server.

Comment: Take a look at this: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/how-do-i-point-another-domain-to-a-sub-folder

Comment: It works if the path points to a root of a different app, but not if the path is a route the same app.
It is my fault to not make it clear enough.
Thanks for your response anyway.